# building a web application using msbuild

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application solution with 14 projects which include web services, class libraries, sub-web applications.. can anyone provide a solution on how to get along with an example?

Comment: I have to write a msbuild script for the structure posted above...

Answer (score 2):

you can create a batch file that contains the below

```
pushd "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"

msbuild "C:\projects\project1.csproj"
msbuild "C:\projects\project2.csproj"
msbuild "C:\projects\project3.csproj"
```

or you can build the solution directly

```
pushd "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"

msbuild "C:\projects\solution.sln"
```